# Replicating a plot using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to replicate the following plot in LaTeX and using `tikz`. I am working on a prototype in R but using R is a little more difficult - especially trying to get the arrows to align correctly with each "jump". How can I make a similar plot using `tikz`? - It is to demonstrat gradient descent with a given learning rate.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to other LaTeX packages like `pgfplot` or possibly, `expl3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly the hardest part is in funding a suitable function to plot, but a little thought shows that something like `x^2/2-3x+5` works. As you want to reuse this function several times I think that the best approach is to declare the function explicitly using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=0.5*\x*\x-3*\x+5;}]
    ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

after which you can draw points using `(a,{f(a)})` for different values of `a`. The braces around the `f(a)` are necessary so that [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) does not get confused about the coordinates of the point being plotted. Here `a` can be anything from an explicit number to a variable in a `\foreach` loop or a `plot` command.

Once this is done some fairly straightforward [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) commands produce:

[image]

Note that, unlike in the image in the OP, I have put the points on top of the function as I think this looks better. To change this all you have to do is move the `plot` command after the `\foreach` loop. I have left the addition of the words "Minimum" and "Learning step" as an exercise:)

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  point/.style = {% define a style for the function points
    circle,
    fill=#1,
    draw=black,
    inner sep=2pt,
  },
  point/.default = {violet!60}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=0.5*\x*\x-3*\x+5;}]
    \draw[thick,-{LaTeX}](0,0)--(6,0) node[right]{$\theta$};
    \draw[thick,-{LaTeX}](0,0)--(0,4) node[above]{Cost};
    \draw[thick, dashed](0.6, {f(0.6)}) -- (0.6,0)
          node[below, text width=4em, align=center]{Random initial value};
    \draw[thick, dashed](3, {f(3)}) -- (3,0) node[below]{$\hat\theta$};
    \draw[domain=0.5:5.5, smooth, thick, gray] plot (\x, f(\x);
    \foreach \a [count=\c, remember=\c as \C] in {0.6, 1.0, ..., 2.6} {
      \node[point] (\c) at (\a, {f(\a)}){};
      \ifnum\c>1 % after the first coordinate draw an arrow
         \draw[->, bend left](\C) to (\c);
      \fi
    }
    \node[point=yellow] (Y) at (3, {f(3)}){}; % add the yellow point
    \draw[->, bend left](6) to (Y);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

More points can be added simply by changing the list of points in the `\foreach` loop (and then updating the `(6)` to the number of points plotted in the last `\draw` command).

Comment: Maybe reduce the arrow head size?

Comment: @Anush Agreed! For the picture above the arrow heads are probably OK. If more points are added it would probably look cramped, so  it would be a good idea to add a style for the arrows that is something like `pointer/.style={-{Stealth[length=1mm]}, bend left}`.